# Message Manager Broken

Tags: java, events, messaging

I'm trying to write a simple Message Manager, but none of my messages are showing up in my queue.

The code that calls it is:

```
//initialize message manager
    CJournal.Journal(Main.class, "Initializing message manager");
    MessageManager messageManager = new MessageManager();
    messageManager.run();

    //send bootstrap message
    CJournal.Journal(Main.class, "Testing messanger: ending bootstrapping message to messagemanager");
    Message boot_strap_message = new Message();
    boot_strap_message.mflag = EEventMachine.EM_BOOTSTRAP;
    messageManager.EnqueueMessage(boot_strap_message);
```

And the message manager code is:

```
public  class MessageManager implements Runnable {

    PriorityQueue<Message> messagesQueue = new PriorityQueue<Message>();


    public void EnqueueMessage(Message message)
    {
        messagesQueue.add(message);
    }

    @Override
    public  void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (true)
        {
            //pull message from queue


            if (!messagesQueue.isEmpty())
            {
                CJournal.Journal(MessageManager.class, "Found a message");
                Message message = messagesQueue.remove();

                //dispatch messages according to their type
                switch(message.mflag)
                {
                case EM_BOOTSTRAP:
                    CJournal.Journal(MessageManager.class, "Messaging system working properly.");
                default:
                    CJournal.Journal(MessageManager.class, "Dispatch Message Trashed");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And the debug output is:

```
13 In Class::class Sampler.Main Journal Entry:Testing Event Manager
14 In Class::class Sampler.Main Journal Entry:Created dummy CEvent. Pushing to event manager.
15 In Class::class Sampler.Main Journal Entry:Initializing message manager
```

I should be getting, "Messaging System working properly"

Any ideas?

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
O`11 In Class::class SchedulingManager.Timer.CTimerManager Journal Entry:Creating a CTimer Object
12 In Class::class SchedulingManager.Timer.CTimerManager Journal Entry:Timer creation success. Adding CTimer object to internal list Of Timers
13 In Class::class Sampler.Main Journal Entry:Testing Event Manager
14 In Class::class Sampler.Main Journal Entry:Created dummy CEvent. Pushing to event manager.
15 In Class::class Sampler.Main Journal Entry:Initializing message manager
16 In Class::class Sampler.Main Journal Entry:Testing messanger: ending bootstrapping message to messagemanager
Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.ClassCastException: MessageManagement.Message cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.siftUpComparable(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.offer(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.add(Unknown Source)
    at MessageManagement.MessageManager.EnqueueMessage(MessageManager.java:69)
    at Sampler.Main.main(Main.java:128)
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.AbstractQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at MessageManagement.MessageManager.run(MessageManager.java:47)
```

And this code:

`public  class MessageManager extends Thread {

```
    @Override
    public  void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (true)
        {

            if (!messagesQueue.isEmpty())
            {
                //pull message from queue
                Message message = messagesQueue.remove();

                //dispatch messages according to their type
                switch(message.mflag)
                {
                case EM_BOOTSTRAP:
                    CJournal.Journal(MessageManager.class, "Messaging system working properly.");
                default:
                    CJournal.Journal(MessageManager.class, "Dispatch Message Trashed");
                }
            }
        }
    }



    public static PriorityBlockingQueue<Message> messagesQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Message>();

    public static void EnqueueMessage(Message message)
    {
        messagesQueue.add(message);
    }
```

And this is how I am declaring my thread:

```
    MessageManager messageManager = new MessageManager();
    messageManager.start();


    //send bootstrap message
    CJournal.Journal(Main.class, "Testing messanger: ending bootstrapping message to messagemanager");
    Message boot_strap_message = new Message();
    boot_strap_message.mflag = EEventMachine.EM_BOOTSTRAP;
    messageManager.EnqueueMessage(boot_strap_message);

    Loop loop = new Loop();  //hand over to game loop
```

I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `run()` on your `MessageManager` from within the same `Thread` which then goes into an infinite loop.

You need to wrap your `MessageManager` in a new `Thread` and start that thread.

```
new Thread(messageManager).start();
```

However you may need to change your [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) if you are going to access it from multiple threads

From JavaDoc:

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. Multiple threads should not access a PriorityQueue instance concurrently if any of the threads modifies the queue. Instead, use the thread-safe PriorityBlockingQueue class.